# Simulating two coupled dynamical systems in Python

Tags: python, ode

The goal is to plot two identical dynamical systems that are coupled.

We have:

X = [x0,x1,x2]

U = [u0,u1,u2]

And

Xdot = f(X) + alpha*(U-X)

Udot = f(U) + alpha*(X-U)

So I wish to plot the solution to this grand system on one set of axes (i.e in xyz for example) and eventually change the coupling strength to investigate the behaviour.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def couple(s,t,a=0.2,beta=0.2,gamma=5.7,alpha=0.03):
    [x,u] = s
    [u0,u1,u2] = u
    [x0,x1,x2] = x
    xdot = np.zeros(3)
    xdot[0] = -x1-x2
    xdot[1] = x0+a*x1
    xdot[2] = beta + x2*(x0-gamma)
    udot = np.zeros(3)
    udot[0] = -u1-u2
    udot[1] = u0+a*u1
    udot[2] = beta + u2*(u0-gamma)
    sdot = np.zeros(2)
    sdot[0] = xdot + alpha*(u-x)
    sdot[1] = udot + alpha*(x-u)
    return sdot

s_init = [0.1,0.1]

t_init=0; t_final = 300; t_step = 0.01
tpoints = np.arange(t_init,t_final,t_step)

a=0.2; beta=0.2; gamma=5.7; alpha=0.03

y = odeint(couple, s_init, tpoints,args=(a,beta,gamma,alpha), hmax = 0.01)
```

I imagine that something is wrong with s_init since it should be TWO initial condition vectors but when I try that I get that "odeint: y0 should be one-dimensional." On the other hand when I try s_init to be a 6-vector I get "too many values to unpack (expected two)." With the current setup, I am getting the error

```
  File "C:/Users/Python Scripts/dynsys2019work.py", line 88, in couple
    [u0,u1,u2] = u

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object
```

Cheers

*Edit: Please note this is basically my first time attempting this kind of thing and will be happy to receive further documentation and references.

Answer (score 0):

The ode definition takes in and returns a 1D vector in scipy odeint, and I think some of your confusion is that you actually have 1 system of ODEs with 6 variables.  You have just mentally apportioned it into 2 separate ODEs that are coupled.

You can do it like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np

def couple(s,t,a=0.2,beta=0.2,gamma=5.7,alpha=0.03):

    x0, x1, x2, u0, u1, u2 = s
    xdot = np.zeros(3)
    xdot[0] = -x1-x2
    xdot[1] = x0+a*x1
    xdot[2] = beta + x2*(x0-gamma)
    udot = np.zeros(3)
    udot[0] = -u1-u2
    udot[1] = u0+a*u1
    udot[2] = beta + u2*(u0-gamma)
    return np.ravel([xdot, udot])

s_init = [0.1,0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
t_init=0; t_final = 300; t_step = 0.01
tpoints = np.arange(t_init,t_final,t_step)
a=0.2; beta=0.2; gamma=5.7; alpha=0.03
y = odeint(couple, s_init, tpoints,args=(a,beta,gamma,alpha), hmax = 0.01)
plt.plot(tpoints,y[:,0])
```